# 2 Cloned Macbooks conflicting

Tags: macos, migration, migration-assistant

I have a Mackbook air m1 from work, and my personal device is also a Mackbook air m1.
When I got the work device. I used migration assistant to clone everything from the personal machine (almost blank). And realized something strange:
Both devices show up as one on many apps (Telegram, Cloudflare WARP, and others). And **the biggest problem is with WiFi**; they both can't almost be connected to my router at the same time. Any ideas?

- I already changed the device id from settings and both have different IDs/names.

I do not want apps to treat both Macs as one.

How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean b y clone? Why not just log in to the same Apple ID? I am using the same Apple ID on 5 macs and they all get to see the iCloud storage...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SolarMike using Migration Assistant to clone data from one mac to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t how migration assistant was designed to work. You will have to take each app in isolation and work out how they identify themselves to the cloud.

You can start with WiFi. Validate that each Mac receives a different IP address from the router.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-icloud-private-relay-mchlecadabe0/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/troubleshoot-joining-a-wi-fi-network-on-mac-mchlp2725/mac

Keep in mind private relay, couldflare WARP and private addresses could confuse both someone unaware of how this is implemented or other apps to see machines as coming from the same router.

- telegram lets you access one stream of chats from two computers (just as Messages and other messaging apps will)

Comment: I validated that each device has its own IP address. and Private Relay is not supported in my region anyway. My WiFi now works but every ~30 mins it'll disconnect one of the 2 devices. It works seamlessly on my iPhone and other non-Apple laptops. I had a feeling it might be the router but then why just the 2 macs are affected?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Do you have an idea regarding this current behavior? Do you think there’s a chance it’s the router?

Comment: Absolutely @mhashim6 if it were the Mac, it would never once connect. Since it works intermittently, it’s almost certainly not a configuration or identity issue and you will want to get access to the network WiFi logs and determine the disconnect reasons.

Comment: Thank you @bmike. I got myself a new decent router and have been testing it for a week now and it works just fine. I also uninstalled conflicting apps and reinstalled them and logged in on each machine separately and everything is working just fine